# selecting conditional code paths in hypothesis

Tags: python, conditional-statements, python-hypothesis

Most conditional strategies seem to be data-driven. But what if I want to select a code path independently of any generated data?

For example, let's convert the grammar `rule_a = rule_optional? rule_b` to a strategy:

```py
@strategy.composite
def rule_a(draw):
  elem_b = draw(rule_b())
  if draw(strategy.sampled_from([False, True])):
    elem_opt = draw(rule_optional())
    elem_b = combine(elem_opt, elem_b)
  return elem_b
```

Say I'm generating a data structure from a grammar, and to test a particular behavior I want to modify the data structure by replacing a single randomly-selected node from a subset of specific locations in the syntax tree. Rewriting the grammar to generate this modified data is too complicated, so I modify the generated structure instead:

```py
@strategy.composite
def generate_maybe_modified(draw):
  data = draw(generate())
  locations = []
  for location, node in iterate(data):
    if match_specific(data, location, node):
      locations.append(location)
  if not draw(strategy.sampled_from([False, True])
    return data
  modified = draw(modified())
  location = draw(strategy.sampled_from(locations))
  data = replace(location, data, modified)
  return data
```

The common idea is to select a code path by randomly selecting from `[False, True]`, where `False` is first to shrink towards the shortest code path. Is this the most efficient solution?

Is there any difference between `draw(strategy.sampled_from([False, True]))` and `random.choice([False, True])` where `random` is managed by Hypothesis, i.e. an instance of a `HypothesisRandom` subclass?

Can I manage probabilities outside of Hypothesis? That is, can I increase the chance of the simpler code path being drawn by instead using:

```py
random.choices([False, True], [90, 10])[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77116488/9297601), it's best to specify only what inputs are *valid*, and let Hypothesis work out the probabilities for you.

> Is there any difference between draw(strategy.sampled_from([False, True])) and random.choice([False, True]) where random is managed by Hypothesis, i.e. an instance of a HypothesisRandom subclass?

These are both more-or-less equivalent to `draw(st.booleans())`, which would be my preferred idiom.

> Most conditional strategies seem to be data-driven. But what if I want to select a code path independently of any generated data? ...
>
> Say I'm generating a data structure from a grammar, and to test a particular behavior I want to modify the data structure by replacing a single randomly-selected node from a subset of specific locations in the syntax tree.  Rewriting the grammar to generate this modified data is too complicated, so I modify the generated structure instead ... Is this the most efficient solution?

A location in the syntax tree *is* generated data, so from Hypothesis' perspective there's nothing unusual going on when it generates the data.

However, this can be inefficient when we try to modify previously-generated examples (during heuristic search, or when shrinking a failing input).  Ideally changes to Hypothesis-controlled decisions will have local effects - e.g. replacing nodes within each subtree rather than the whole example means that fewer mutations will invalidate replay of a later decision - but it's unlikely to be a big problem if this is impractical.